# How to convert a SQL query into hibernate criteria?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, criteria

```
SELECT th.`id`,th.`type`,th.`url_label`,url.`url`,COUNT(th.`id`) FROM 
`threat` th LEFT JOIN `threat_url` url ON th.`id`= url.`threat_id` 
WHERE th.enterprise_id=1816 AND th.`status` != 'deleted'  GROUP BY 
th.`id` ORDER BY COUNT(th.`id`) DESC ;
```

Comment: Can you give us more details about your entities ??